# Getting list of context variables out of string

Tags: python, django

I have the following string in my Django app: `"Hello, {{ name }}. I will arrive at {{ time }}"`. My goal is to come up with a list of variables that is used in that string:

```
def my_func():
   # What should be done here ?

my_str = "Hello, {{ name }}. I will arrive at {{ time }}"
print(my_func(my_str))  # Desired output ["name", "time"]
```

The desired output here should be `["name", "time"]`.
Currently, I am going to implement that invoking a regexp, but I feel like there must be some in-built way to achieve that. Any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`jinja2schema.infer`](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2schema/)** to get the list of variables used in template:

```
import jinja2schema

def my_func(my_str):
   return list(jinja2schema.infer(my_str).keys())

my_str = "Hello, {{ name }}. I will arrive at {{ time }}"
variables = my_func(my_str)
```

`variables` should look like:

```
['time', 'name']
```

Comment: Adding new dependency for this ? Is it a good idea ?

Comment: well, I don't have any idea about drawbacks, but it is built to interact with `jinja2` templates tho

Comment: It's common advice not to use regex for structured data formats like HTML, JSON, etc. when there are modules to parse them. It seems reasonable to do the same for a known template format like Django uses, if there's a module to do it.